# pegjs regular expression match words up until a word from a collection of words is found

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, peg, pegjs

I am using the pegjs parser generator for a project and I am having difficulty creating a grammar that should match all words up until a collection of words that it should not match. as an example in the string "the door is yellow" I want to be able to match all words up until is, tell the pegjs parser to start parsing from the word is. The collection of words I want to the parser to break on are "is" "has" and "of".

current grammar rule is as follows:

```
subject "sub" = 
s:[a-zA-Z ]+ { return s.join("").trim()}
```

How can i create a look ahead that stops the parser from including my collection on words?

```
(!of|is|has)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was asked 5 years ago, but I'm just running through cleaning up unanswered questions in the [pegjs] tag.

This seems to work, and you just need to replace `postfix` with your further processing rule.

```
subject "sub" =  prefix:prefix breakWord:breakWord postfix:postfix "\n"? {
  return { prefix: prefix, breakWord, postfix }
}

prefix = $(!breakWord .)* { return text().trim() }
postfix = [^\n]* { return text().trim() }

breakWord
  = "is"
  / "has"
  / "of"
```

which generates this with an input of "the door is yellow":

```json
{ prefix: "the door", breakWord: "is", postfix: "yellow" }
```

Note a couple of things:

- The form `(!breakWord .)` is a little slow; it looks ahead to make sure the current input doesn't begin with any of the words in the `breakWord` set of alternates -- for each character in the prefix.
- If you have break words that start with a common set of characters (e.g. "is" and "isn't"), make sure the longer word is first in the `breakWord` rule.
- The current `postfix` rule assumes that a newline might terminate the input.

Answer (score -1):

This will work

```
.+(?=\s+(of|is|has))
```

It matches one or more of any characters (except line breaks) until it encounters  either 'of', 'is', or 'has' (via a positive lookahead) with white space before them.